# Calculate the Lebesgue integral

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Calculate the Lebesgue integral

$$ \int_{[0,\pi]}^{} \sin x\: \epsilon[\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}] d\mu,$$

where is $\epsilon $ is the characteristic function.

I tried this way $ \int_{\mathsf ([0,\pi ] \cap I) }^{} \sin x \: d\mu$...

$\mathsf ([0,\pi ] \cap I)$ = $[0,\pi ]$..

$ \int^{\pi}_0 \sin x \: d\mu=-\cos(\pi)+\cos(0)=2$

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand your question..edit it please

Comment: What is $I$ defined to be?

Comment: What is $ε[R \ Q]$??

Comment: I = Irrational numbers, R = real numbers, Q = rational numbers, of course

Comment: $\int_{E}^{} f d\mu = \int_{}^{} f \epsilon(E) d\mu$ I thought you knew that.

Comment: Use that $\epsilon(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}) = 1$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are not far, just use that $m([0,\pi])=m((R-Q) \cap [0,\pi])$

And the fact that if $m(E)=0$ then $\int_Ef=0$ for some measurable $E$ and $f$ integrable.(where $f$ can also be negative)

> $\int_{\mathbb{Q \cap [0,\pi]}}\sin{x}=0$ because $m( \mathbb{Q} \cap[0,\pi])=0$
>
> So  $$\int_{(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,\pi]} \sin{x}=\int_0^{\pi}\sin{x}-\int_{\mathbb{Q \cap [0,\pi]}}\sin{x}=\int_0^{\pi}\sin{x}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $1_{E}$ be the charecteristic function and $m$ be the Lebesgue measure (Note that $m$ is not a variable). Then 
$$\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x)1_{(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})}dm=\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x) dm-\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x)1_{\mathbb{Q}}dm$$

Since $\sin(x)$ is positive on the interval $[0,\pi]$ and bounded above by 
$1$ we see that:

$$0\leq\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x)1_{\mathbb{Q}}dm\leq  \int_{[0,\pi]}1_\mathbb{Q}dm=m(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,\pi])=0$$

So 
$$\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x)1_{(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})}dm=\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x) dm$$

In the case of riemann integratable functions on a closed inteval like $\sin(x)$ the Lebesgue integral just becomes the riemann integral:

$$\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x)dm=\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x)dx=-\cos(\pi)+\cos(0)=2$$

so

$$\int_{[0,\pi]}\sin(x)1_{(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})}dm=2$$